# Matlab Curve fitting returns different parameter values every time

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to fit some data with the following equation, which is a modified error function and contains 4 unknown parameters (I'm mainly interested in **par4**):

```
Y = par1+(par2*(erf((X-par3)/ par4)))
```

If I set some sensible start points, the data point are fitted reasonably well (R-square ~ 0.95) but the error on some of the parameters found has a very wide range. Below is a image of the data to fit, the fitted curve and the parameters found.

Data and fit:

[image: Data and Fit]

```
   par4 =      0.9109  (-52.89, 54.71)
   par2 =     0.02647  (0.02421, 0.02872)
   par3 =       38.15  (8.128, 68.18)
   par1 =      0.8647  (0.8624, 0.867)
```

If I change even slightly the start points (e.g. for par4, from 0.5 to 0.1), the final fit values change. Similarly, if I make `TolFun value larger the final parameters and their error change as well as the fit. In some cases, I'm even presented with no error intervals for the found parameters. For instance (if I set par4 start point = 3 and the others remain unchanged) I get:

```
   par4 =      0.1712
   par2 =     0.02674
   par3 =       38.63
   par1 =      0.8649  (0.8625, 0.8672)
```

As you can imagine, I'm no expert in the maths of the fitting process but I thought that the different results mean that the data is poor (no data points in the centre of the curve) and many curves can reproduce it with a relatively good R-square. Also, the large error intervals may mean that the spread in the data is large. Are my thoughts correct?

Also, what does the option `TolFun` control? And, I know the error intervals are calculated on 95% (2sigma) criterion; can I change that to 68% (1sigma) to have a narrower error interval?

Comment: I'd say your suspicions are correct. Try plotting a few of these fits with different parameters: you'll probably see that they are essentially the same. Especially for `par4`: that describes the width of your transition, but you don't have enough data to precisely describe that. Also: [R-squared is not a good indicator of a good fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet)

Comment: Do you need to use that function? You could modify it slightly to better fit the start and end portions. For example, this would work much better: `par1 + (par2*(erf((X - par3)/par4))) + par5*X^2 + par6*X`

Comment: @AndrasDeak, Thanks for the advice and for the link. As well as graphing data, I do need a statistical parameter to describe the goodness of the fit; What else could I use together with or in place of R-squared to indicate a good fit?

Comment: @BrianLynch, Unfortunately, I have to fit the data with the function I posted

Comment: I'm not too versed in this area to be able to suggest something else as an indicator. I also generally look at R-squared to get a first idea, but (to me) the bottom line is given by the visual correspondence of data vs. model. So my comment was more of a warning: don't be fooled by just the R-squared itself.